# Chaning numbers in hotspot map with CSS

Tags: html, css, counting

I have a question about this HTML 5 hotspot map I am trying to make. By Default the numbers start with 1 (glowing hotspots). But I need to get the links to start at 7.

```
.cq-hotspots .hotspot-item a i {
display: block;
font-size: 12px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-style: normal;
color: #fff;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

}

Is there a way to make the counting start at 7 instead of 1 using only CSS?

Webpage: http://www.welzendesign.com/drielandenpunt/dagje-drielandenpunt/plattegrond/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you cannot change text using css. You would have to use JavaScript/JQuery instead

Comment: But by default it starts with 1 there is no way to change the default counting ?

Comment: Well technically if it was contained in content in a psuedo you could (i.e. :before or :after). Wouldn't be dynamic.

Comment: @Vonwelzen Yes, but not using css. You would need to change some of the code instead

Comment: It doesnt need to be dynamic could you elaborate on how this is done?